# Well-known parent/child pairs in the field of OR

Tags: people

Does the apple fall not far from the tree in operations research? Who are well-known Parent/Child pairs in operations research?  I can't claim this: my father was a chemist and my son, at fifteen, has not yet caught the OR bug.

Comment: I would like to argue in favor of this question. It is of historic interest, and seems not too broad, since there are not so many OR parent/child pairs, neither is it opinion-based, since the facts can be checked. Could one of the "too broad"ers bring forward some arguments?

Comment: I also think the question is fine

Comment: I agree; I think this question falls under the meta question [Are questions about the *field* of OR on-topic?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/are-questions-about-the-field-of-or-on-topic), for which the consensus is "yes". Moreover, it is not too broad and not opinion-based, as @MarcusRitt pointed out.

Comment: How is this too broad? Overmoderation of this site is not and will not be a good thing. By analogy with one of my downvoted questions, perhaps the put on holders think there should be separate questions for father-son, father-daughter, mother-son, mother-daughter, father-nonbinary, mother-nonbinary, ...

Answer (score 23):

Another father-daughter pair is Matteo Fischetti of U. of Padova and his daughter Martina Fischetti who recently completed her Ph.D. at DTU with David Pisinger.

Are we still waiting for mother-child pairs? Hopefully soon...

Comment: Embarassed that I didn't write that one. Since it was Mike Trick's Twitter post https://twitter.com/miketrick/status/1138218852817543168  that pointed me to the question.

Comment: Also, does @Fischenders count as a child/clone/alter-ego/split-personality in the context of this question?

Comment: Wait!!!!  You mean Fishenders isn't a real person?!?!?

Answer (score 19):

In Montreal we have Louis M Rousseau whose father Jean Marc Rousseau was also a professor until he quit academua to start his own company (GIRO).

From Chile there is Gabriel Weintraub, professor at Stanford and the son of Andres Weintraub.

From Brazil, there's Daniel Aloise, professor at PolyMtl, the son of Dario Aloise from Natal RN.

Answer (score 19):

For sure there is Bob Bixby and Ann Bixby.  Ann did her Ph.D. at Northwestern with Collette Coullard.
Also, a bit of a stretch, since his father was more of a mathematician, but there is also Gunnar Carlsson (Stanford Math) and Jon Carlsson, who is currently at USC.

Comment: Based on my topological data analysis, I group the Carlssons together as O.R.

Answer (score 18):

How about [George Dantzig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Dantzig) and his father [Tobias Dantzig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobias_Dantzig), who (according to wikipedia) also had a PhD in Mathematics.

Comment: As far as I know, Tobias made two contributions to O.R: 1) having the kid and 2) suggesting the term "primal" as the problem for which the dual is the dual.

Answer (score 16):

John D.C. Little, of $L = \lambda W$ fame : father

John N. "Jack" Little https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_N._Little and https://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/founders/jacklittle.html, President and co-founder of The Mathworks (MATLAB): son

Jack received degrees (S.B. from  M.I.T.) in Electrical Engineering. Given that when I was accepted into the M.I.T. O.R. Ph.D. program, I was assigned to the Electrical Engineering (course 6) department, and in light of Jack's role in the development of MATLAB, which is heavily used in O.R., being second only to Cleve Moler, I think we can consider Jack to be close enough to O.R. for government work.

Answer (score 14):

[Frederick Hillier](https://www.informs.org/Explore/History-of-O.R.-Excellence/Biographical-Profiles/Hillier-Frederick-S) and [Mark Hillier](http://faculty.washington.edu/mhillier/biography.htm), known for their [OR textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003ZM0SES).

Comment: Ann, who is Fred's wife/Mark's mother, has BS and MS in Statistics, so that could also count as O.R. So this is sort of a parent/child trio.

Answer (score 12):

There are [Robert Tibshirani](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/), the father of the LASSO, and his son [Ryan Tibshirani](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/). Even though they mainly work in statistics they also have made some valuable contributions to the OR-community such as the LASSO, several contributions in Machine Learning or [this comparison](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/bestsubset.pdf) of regression methods.

Answer (score 11):

I learned of another one recently. Again depending on how broad your definition of "OR" is. There is Jim Orlin from MIT and his son Ben Orlin, of Math With Bad Drawings fame.  (https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/)

Answer (score 10):

Only few of you may know [Erik Demaine](http://www.erikdemaine.org) who is not only a computer science prodigy and artist, but so is his father, Martin. They publish together.

Answer (score 10):

Raffaele Cerulli from U. Salerno and his daughter Martina Cerulli — PhD student in Paris with Leo Liberti and Claudia D’Ambrosio.

Answer (score 8):

François Louveaux (mostly known for the book on stochastic programming he coauthored with John Birge) and Quentin Louveaux, both of them in Belgium (UNamur and ULiège, respectively).