# Operations research trivia facts

Tags: history

Sorry if this is off-topic, but can anyone recommend some resources to find trivia facts about operations research? Like the fact that Abraham Lincoln had to solve a 14-city TSP as a lawyer, or that Roger Corman studied industrial engineering at Stanford, or the story about George Dantzig solving the two open problems on the blackboard as a grad student?

Comment: Here is one category of O.R. trivia "Well-known parent/child pairs in the field of OR"  https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/357/well-known-parent-child-pairs-in-the-field-of-or  .And an OR/MS Today article "Like father, like son and daughter
All in the family tree: INFORMS rich with O.R. legacies" https://pubsonline.informs.org/do/10.1287/orms.2020.01.15/full/ , perhaps inspired by that OR Stack Exchange thread.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a trivia fact or a fact about trivia, but Sam Buttrey, associate professor of OR at the Naval Postgraduate School, [won big](https://pubsonline.informs.org/do/10.1287/LYTX.2021.06.18n/full/) on the trivia quiz show *Jeopardy*. (Hopefully my use of the term "trivia" won't result in *Jeopardy* fans besieging my house.)

It may be stretching the definition of operations research a little, but there's an interesting story about [Abraham Wald's work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Wald) with the US Army Air Force in WW II.

Comment: I don't consider the Abraham Wald story to be a stretch at all. That is O.R. much more than a lot of gobbledy gook math with no relation to reality which passes as O.R. in some circles.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Agreed about the tenuous connection to reality. What I meant by a stretch was whether it would be considered OR v. statistics (or, today, "analytics").

Comment: I get that.  Statistics is a key field contributing to O.R. Wald made an O.R. contribution, drawing on Statistics.  I don't agree with the view of analytics being end to end, and O.R. being just a collection of tools. I view O.R. as end to end, and that's now I usually practice it.